# how to overwrite a global variable in inner class

Tags: android, scope, global-variables, global

i want to over write a global variable in the inner class which is outside of the on create method.

```
    public class MainMenuActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    String user_type;

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

    user_type="collion";
        result();
    //print user_type

    }

    private void result(){
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(!getData(dataSnapshot)){
                    user_type="vendor";
                    inti(user_type);
                    result();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };
        uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);

    }
}
```

But it still gives user_type collision not vendor. please help me on this

Comment: you should set a break point to see if  user_type="vendor"; is even being triggered

Comment: Did you find cause to the problem. Is this working for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/51389175/3624647 ?

Answer (score 1):

As per your code in your `result()` method you have added `ValueEventListener`, Which is I suppose from **Firebase**. This is ***asynchronous call*** so you cannot possibly except that `public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)` method will get called as soon as you called result() method.

This will happen asynchronously, so when you try to print `user_type` field after calling result() method the old value is printed as new value is not yet updated.

In conclusion,

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if(!getData(dataSnapshot)){
        user_type="vendor";
        inti(user_type);
        result();
    }
}
```

As this method will **not be called synchronously**, It will not update that field right away and thus print statement will **print original data** in that Field

Answer (score 0):

Just use `MainMenuActivity.user_type = "vendor" inside the inner class`, so the code knows you are referencing the MainMenuActivity class member.

Comment: It will not make any difference. As there is only one Field name `user_type` and no other. No conflict will occur. Its because of callback delay

Comment: Oh, yes, I actually had misunderstood the problem. Your answer addresses correctly!